# Haven't yet received Census badge - Claim it manually?

Tags: support, badges, survey-2021

About ten hours ago I did the yearly [developer survey](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/05/25/the-2021-developer-survey-is-now-open/). As of now I haven't received the reward - though it appears that the badge page is being updated [every minute](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census).

I can't re-do the test due to the message:

> You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired.

Is there any chance to claim the badge manually?

Comment: Did you press the button on the past page that said something along "Claim the census badge"? After pressing it, you should have seen [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qCVC.png).

Comment: @Scratte No, didn't know that there was such a page. The survey ended with a thank you note for participating. Any clue what I could do now? Contact a moderator? I can't re-do the survey!

Comment: The "thank you note for participating" page had that one button on the left and another on the right. They are small default browser buttons and appear right under the "thank you". In my case they were grayish and quite long since they contained the text mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Bug (?) Fix:** After the survey I apparently wasn't redirected to the award page and I couldn't re-do the test. Therefore I decided to do the test on another browser (to bypass *"You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired."*) and copy the URL `https://stackoverflow.com/dev-survey/claim-badge?award=ID` into the browser I was logged in with SO.

The claim was successful and I received the award within ten minutes!

Comment: That.. smells like a hack.. anyone that has or hasn't filled the survey can send that, no?

Comment: @Scratte Thought so as well - my assumption is that the ID at the end determines a one time claim. I can send you the link with the already used badge, it just shows a "Thank You!" note.

Comment: Yes, it determines a one time claim, probably because you can't get it more than once and that may be a check on the Stack side. But that doesn't mean that someone that **didn't** do the survey, can't just use your hack and get the badge.

Comment: @Scratte That is correct. You could use the link by someone else to claim the badge.

Comment: So I guess the question remains: Can someone use the link with an ID that belongs to another user and then they will get the badge? If so.. it seems a little more than just hacky. (Unless I'm completely mistaken about what the ID represents).

Comment: Yes, as done in my case. To be fair, I completed the survey twice - but claimed the badge via the second link (from another browser). By the way, the ID doesn't belong to "another user" as the survey is anonymous. After completion you'll be redirected to a page on which you can claim the reward (it isn't user-specific).